# Disable direct access to certain files (include)

Tags: php

I'm triyng to blobk access to certain files.
I have on my server many files like this

```
filename_sql.php
```

Basically i need to disallow user to access directly to **sql.php** files:

http://url.com/filename_sql.php <<<

I have created an htaccess with this code, but i can access files direcly calling url.
What do I wrong?

```
<Files ~ "\.sql(.php)?$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Put them on a level upper than a webroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex expression is matching filenames that end in `".sql.php"`, but the example filename you listed ends with `"_sql.php"`

If you remove the first period, it should match requests like `"filename_sql.php"` (or anything ending with `"sql.php"`):

```
<Files ~ "sql(\.php)?$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

But, an even better method for keeping these files from being directly accessed, would be to move them outside of the **root/public** directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick

```
<Files ~ "\.sql(\.php)?$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

You forgot to put \ before .php.